# ControllerAdvice conditionally handle exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception, controller-advice

I have a controller advice that handles the exceptional behavior in my REST controller and I came across a situation when I have to conditionally process `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` that have a certain message (the one for duplicate keys), returning a `409`, letting the other ones be handled by the default handler (returning a `500` error code).

I am thinking of 2 possible ways to achieve that:

1. Throwing a new bare-boned `Exception` on the else branch on my condition, so the handling is done by Spring.
2. Explicitly calling the general exception handler (like `return handleGeneralException(exception)` from inside my else branch).

I there a "proper" way to pass on a fraction of exceptions of one kind in my `ControllerAdvice` to another handler than the "original" one?

EDIT 1:
I would like to do something like this in my ControllerAdvice:

```
if (exception.getMessage.contains("something")) {
    // handle exception
} else {
    // pass to other handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a custom exception class and then when you throw the `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`  wrap it in your custom exception classs with additional fields whatever you want to be accessible in controller advice. Handle the custom exception in your controller advice class.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(YourCustomException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleNotFoundException(YourCustomExceptionex,
            WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.getReasonPhrase());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

}
```

While having the try catch block to handle this exception in your code , make sure that you handle `DataIntegrityViolationException` instead of `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` if you are using **Spring Data JPA**. So , if you are using Spring Data Jpa then :

```
try {
    anyRepository.save(new YourModel(..));
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("history already exist");in res
    throw New YourCustomException("additional msg if you need it ", e);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that that is a runtime exception - where could I possible handle and wrap it? there in the controller advice? I mean, I do not ever handle it in my code

Comment: Have a try catch bloc for your code and in the catch block handle `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ` by rethrowing it as your custom exception class.

Comment: my question is where should I have that try-catch block. please see my edit

Comment: @AvramPop Have the try catch for the code block which is going to throw this exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will capture the error message of exception SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in ControllerAdbvice without having to handle in code

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(value = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> dataIntegrityViolationExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
ExceptionResponse response = new ExceptionResponse();
    Throwable throwable = ex.getCause();
    while (throwable != null) {
        if (throwable instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
            String errorMessage = throwable.getMessage();
            response.setErrors(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(errorMessage)));
        }
        throwable = throwable.getCause();
    }       
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
}
```

Comment: you probably did not understand the question... I want to do something like if(throwable.getCause().equals("somecause")) return new ResponseEntity<>; else <pass to another handler> (see my edit)